# What is the the generalization of Euler angles for O(3)?

Tags: rotations

Is there a generalization of Euler angles that handles the case where inversions are allowed?

I'm trying to figure out how to parameterize elements of $O(3)$ for a computer application; if I was only concerned with rotations, I'd use Euler angles, but my problem also allows for inversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $O(3)$ is the disjoint union of $SO(3)$ and $A$, where $A$ consists of all matrices in $SO(3)$ multiplied by the negative identity, the best hope you have is to take a parameterization of $SO(3)$ and make two copies of it, i.e., if you have a space $X$ and a parameterization 
$$
P: X \to SO(3),
$$
define
$$
Q: X \times \{-1, 1 \} \to O(3) : (x, t) \mapsto t P(X).
$$
$Q$ is then a parameterization of $O(3)$.

Comment: I think that you're missing a $1$ in the second equation.

Comment: Fixed; thanks much!